# Cakephp 2.x find first entry of releated model

Tags: cakephp, gallery, model-associations

I know that i can easily find related model-data through model associations, if I select a single entry. But what I want to do is to get the first image as a thumb for the galery, when I use find('all') for the index-page.

My relations (Galleries are named Albums) are:

```
 //Album-Model
public $hasMany = array(
    'Picture' => array(
        'className' => 'Picture',
        'foreignKey' => 'album_id',
        'dependent' => true,
        'conditions' => ''
    )
);
```

and:

```
    public $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'Album' => array(
        'className' => 'Album',
        'foreignKey' => 'album_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT : 
This should worked I tested it on my own!

Before your query add the following lane to specify the recursivity.

```
$this->Albums->recursive = 1;
$this->set('Albums', $this->Album->find('all'));
```

This way, it will also send the Pictures data. Then in your model associations, you can specify to only return the first image with the Album if that's what you want!

Just add `'limit' => '1',` in your `hasMany => Comments` array, in Album Model.

Then you can iterate in your view doing

```
foreach($Albums as $Album){
     $Album['Album']; // ALBUMS info do whatever
     $Album['Picture']; // The thumbnail
}
```

EDIT2: I've just see you can also do

```
$this->Album->find('all', array('recursive' => 1));
```

Comment: I knew that, but I want to find it for all galleries when - for example - using: $this->Album->find('all');

Comment: There are no pictures associated with the model when I use find('all'). There are only if I use >> $this->set('album', $this->Album->read(null, $id)) <<. Thats why i think that my modells are set up correctly. Maybe it shows this behaviour to save memory?

Comment: thx alot! set limit is not an option here, but i'm sure i will find a workaround to reduce the pulled data.

Comment: I'd avoid using recursive and look at the [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) behavior :)